# Defining 'First Commit' in Lead Time Metric and Strategies for Small Batches in Deployment Frequency?

Tags: git, devops, gitlab

I'm try to improve our deliver time from start to end. I read google post about [4key metrics](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/using-the-four-keys-to-measure-your-devops-performance). I have questions that don't find answers in any post.

1- Lead time definition is "The amount of time it takes a commit to get into production". When do you push first commit ? For example I have task. I can do big part of task and send as first commit. What is the meaning of first commit ? Is that empty commit for starting calculation or this commit contains minimal changes ?

2- Deployment Frequency definition is "How often an organization successfully releases to production". To improve this metric it suggests that release often and in small batches but no one define small batches. For example our task is adding getFiltered endpoint. We want to getting data from db then filter it. Should I add to controller and empty service class then commit and deploy to the production. After that, Add service code then deploy again? Or creating testable code so creating controller service and test together then deploy to the production. But if i do that deployment frequency increasing slowly

How should the first commit be? How can I define small batch boundaries ?

Answer (score 3):

> 1- Lead time definition is "The amount of time it takes a commit to
> get into production". When do you push first commit ? For example I
> have task. I can do big part of task and send as first commit. What is
> the meaning of first commit ? Is that empty commit for starting
> calculation or this commit contains minimal changes ?

I find this to be a poor definition of "lead time". Traditionally, lead time measures the time from a request being submitted to the time the request is completed. In the context of software development, that usually means the time from feature request or bug report to the feature request being satisfied or the bug being fixed. This definition is closer to what I'm familiar with as "cycle time".

You can measure time from various points. There are various things that happen in the life cycle of a change. Minimally, there are three steps - the change is requested, work on the change is initiated, the change is made. Depending on your process, you may have other steps. Perhaps the change needs to be reviewed or the change needs to go through formal verification. You can measure the time between various steps that are meaningful based on your process.

To give a specific example, one team that I worked with captured three different time points: (1) when a developer started working on a change, often by making a feature branch to do the work, (2) when the change was merged into the integration branch for release, (3) when the release was deployed into production. Using these three times, the team could understand when work was not flowing through the process effectively and what aspects of the process to look at for potential problems and improvements.

Creating a [value stream map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-stream_mapping), or at least being able to visualize your workflow (such as on a Kanban board), would be the first step to identifying the key events in your process. As work moves through the workflow, you can capture times and measure your process. There's no one-size-fits-all solution, but consistency is necessary to measure the same thing for different work items moving through the workflow.

> 2- Deployment Frequency definition is "How often an organization
> successfully releases to production". To improve this metric it
> suggests that release often and in small batches but no one define
> small batches. For example our task is adding getFiltered endpoint. We
> want to getting data from db then filter it. Should I add to
> controller and empty service class then commit and deploy to the
> production. After that, Add service code then deploy again? Or
> creating testable code so creating controller service and test
> together then deploy to the production. But if i do that deployment
> frequency increasing slowly

This depends on your organization.

A team that is practicing Continuous Deployment using [trunk-based development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) with [feature toggles](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) and [keystone interfaces](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/KeystoneInterface.html) is going to look different than a team using [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) with longer-lived feature branches and scheduled release/deployments. There are cases where deployment can be more expensive - for example, when working in regulated environments where you need strict segregation of duties and change control processes in place. It may not make sense to deploy before user-facing value has been realized because of the amount of time and/or human effort needed to deploy a change.

The important number is not the raw deployment frequency. You need to consider deployment frequency within the broader context of the stakeholders' ability to consume those changes and the technical practices of the team. There is a difference between being able to deploy a change to production quickly (such as to resolve a critical defect, patching a security vulnerability, or deliver a time-sensitive change) and deploying to production frequently.

Generally, though, smaller changes are easier to test, deploy, and validate, which is why you want to increase the deployment frequency. However, you also want changes that make sense to put through that test, deploy, and validate pipeline. If something goes wrong, you can more easily fix a problem (and fail-forward) or roll back to a stable version. But there is such a thing as deploying too frequently.

Answer (score 1):

1. Lead time - realistically what's important to the business is how long it takes from the moment a developer is available to work on something (i.e they finished there last task) before it gets to production and is usable by a customer. Measuring specifically how long it takes for the commit to get to production - is a measure of the rest of the infrastructure/process that supports the developers. I.e. reducing the number is generally considered beneficial.
2. Deployment Frequency - What this is really eluding to is if you can push individual features to production (ideally when ready) or if you have to batch them i.e. one release to production every two weeks.

If developers find it useful to push multiple commits as part of the same feature request - you may want to measure that, however I would back that up by looking at what it's doing to the feature level metrics (are you getting more features out sooner) if not it's just gamification of who can do the most commits, this also applies to commit sizes if its not having a beneficial effect it's just gamification.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Lead time definition is "The amount of time it takes a commit to get into production". When do you push first commit ?

For this metric, there is nothing special about a first commit compared to a second or third commit.

To calculate the lead time, you should measure how much time has elapsed between a developer making a commit and that commit being available in production (i.e., the customer can see and use the changes). Then you average those per-commit lead time numbers to get the average lead time (which is the value normally reported under the heading of Lead Time).

> 2- Deployment Frequency definition is "How often an organization successfully releases to production". To improve this metric it suggests that release often and in small batches but no one define small batches.

There are several ways to define a release schedule. Two common ways with large batches are

- We release twice a year and we release then all the features that were completed in the preceding half year.
- We release when *this* group of features has been completed.

To decrease the batches and release more often, you would either release more times a year (for example, every 2 weeks, instead of twice a year), or you would reduce the number of features you would collect until making a release.

The highest frequency you get is when you release a feature as soon as the developers and testers agree that the feature is complete. For small features, this could result in multiple releases per day.

Comment: You said that "For this metric, there is nothing special about a first commit compared to a second or third commit" actually it's important. When we start the task firstly switch to new branch then doing someting and push the first commit. We push many commits  following merge request. MR merged to trunk branch and deployed to prod. We calculate lead time like that this first commit time - deploy time so if I push first commit with lots of line changes lead time will be less. What should developer do for measure correctly ?

Comment: Thanks for answer for deployment frequency. I understand that if commit is testable, ready for customer then we should deploy to the prod. I saw different approaches for example some teams add feature flag and deploy often. Of course they deployment frequency is increasing. I think commits deploys to prod when ready for use

Comment: @anilcosar, the really correct measure for lead time is from when the developer picks up the task until it is deployed (as also stated in the answer by @DavidT). Then it doesn't matter anymore how much time the developer was working on thing locally (or possibly only in their head) before making the first commit.

Comment: @anilcosar, when trying to optimize lead time, don't look at how fast the developers work, but rather at the delays that the process creates, such as the 2 week delay before the overworked architect has time to approve the MR (as an example).